# In Remix switching from "JavaScript VM" to "Injected web3"

Tags: contract-development

have tested on "JavaScript VM"....all OK.
Have switched to "Injected web 3" to see real chain  behaviour.
On "Deploy" I am getting Send Transaction failed: invalid address. if you use an injected provider please make sure it is unlocked.

Also I notice my "Account" combo in remix is empty.
Any one help on what to do to proceed ?
thx /L

Comment: Hi there. Do you have Metamask installed in your browser? If not, that's your first step. (You'll then need some test ETH for whichever test network you want to test on.)

Comment: Thanks, yes I have Metamask installed and have got 4 eth from faucet. Metamask is set for the ropsten test network.